# properties and methods of child objects in ArrayList not visible

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have here a simple example just to show the problem I have: 
I have a **Card** Class, with property "price".
Of this Card class I have 2 children, **Copper** class and **Silver** class, each with the price they inherit and with their won value.
Now I make an ArrayList "hand" in which I put 2 copper cards and 1silver card.  Until here OK.  with the statement System.out.println(hand.get(0)); I get "I am a Copper card" which is OK. With System.out.println(hand.get(0).getClass()); I get "class Copper" which is also OK.. BUT, System.out.println(hand.get(0).getValue()); dos not work, the getValue() method from Copper is not accessible, only the getPrice() method from Card class..
I looked at similar problems here but no answer works.. Who can help mer! thanks  alot!
PS here is the code

```
public class Card {

    int price;
    public Card(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return new String ("I am a card");
    }
}

public class Copper extends Card {

    int value;
    public Copper(int price, int value) {
        super(price);
        this.value = value;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return new String ("I am a Copper card");
    }
}

public class Silver extends Card{

    int value;
    public Silver(int price, int value) {
        super(price);
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return new String ("I am a Silver card");
    }
 }

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 public class Start {

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Card Card1 = new Copper(0,1);
        Card Card2 = new Copper(0,1);
        Card Card3 = new Silver(3,2);
        ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
        hand.add(Card1);
        hand.add(Card2);
        hand.add(Card3);
        System.out.println(hand.get(0));
        System.out.println(hand.get(0).getClass()); // --> OK
        System.out.println(hand.get(0).getPrice()); // --> OK
        System.out.println(hand.get(0).getValue()); // --> NOT OK                   
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Card` class doesn't have a `getValue()` method - what do you expect it to call? It sounds like `Card` should probably be abstract and declare an abstract method `getValue()` (or put the functionality in `Card` itself).

Comment: thanks.  However with getClass() it returns Copper and not Card..

Comment: Yes, because that's getting the type of the object you call it on *at runtime*. It's very important to understand the difference between compile-time type and runtime-type.

Comment: thanks Jon, clear now!  I made Card abstract and declared the abstract methods, it works like this!  I will do some extra reading on compile-time and run-time types ;-)

Comment: @JonSkeet is absolutely right! The problem is that when the compiler "reads" the code it sees you've defined a list of `Card`-objects. At that moment, the only thing it can do is say: "Ok, it's a list of `Card` objects. It may be `Coper` objects, it may be `Silver` objects or both of them. I'm not sure. As I'm only sure all objects will be `Card` -objects, I will only allow methods defined in the `Card` class.". **The compiler won't run your code: it won't create objects and call methods on it! It will only read and analyze your code**. It has no idea what the `getClass` method will return.**

Comment: hey guys, thanks a lot!  it makes sense when you "think" as a compiler before really running.  Is there a better appoach here?   I made that superclass Card because in a hand I want to treat all Cards the same, without making reference to a special child.  So hand is an ArrayList of Cards because it can be copper, silver, gold, action, points,...

Comment: Well do you really need the subclasses at all? Why not pass the value and the price to the `Card` constructor, and maybe a "name" as a string to return in `toString()`? It sounds like every card has those pieces of state (value, price, display name) but there's no real specialization...

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println(hand.get(0).getValue()); // --> NOT OK
```

because you declared the List: `ArrayList<Card> hand`, so all elements are `Card` type, however you don't have `getValue()` method in your `Card` class.

You can create the `getValue()` in your super class (`Card`), and let sub-classes override it, if your subclass needs do something special with this method.

Comment: @Bart it is correct, because getClass() returns the runtime class of the object. read the api, and do some testing.